# Python : issue running XLRD

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm testing newly installed 'xlrd' package :

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python

import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('D:\excel\test.xls')

print (wb.sheets())
```

I run it through IDLE (Windows 7) and I get the following error message:

```
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:19:30) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\excel\testxls.py", line 3, in <module>
    import xlrd
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1187
    print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Any idea on this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Your python version is `python 3.3.3`  but xlrd is was written for `python 2.x`.

Comment: OK... Is it possible to install python 2.x in parallel with python 3.3?

Comment: xlrd should work for python3, unless you installed it incorrectly

Comment: Note that the `'\t'` in `'D:\excel\test.xls'` will be interpreted as a TAB character by Python, you should escape the backslashes (write `\\ ` or use slashes -- `'D:/excel/test.xls'`)

Comment: I removed 'xlrd' directory manually, then downloaded xlrd-0-9-3.tar.gz from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd. I saved the file in C:\ and executed the installation through Windows cmd shell : cd in unzipped xlrd-0-9-3 directory and then `setup.py install`. The same invalid syntax error is displayed in the cmd window...

Comment: Should be possible to install both. The question is why you want them? Also, don't install 3rd party python packages without using virtualenv.

Comment: I need xlrd, so if it doesn't work on Python3...

Comment: You can try to run 2to3 on xlrd. Obviously the print statement is wrong and 2to3 should fix it and other obvious things.

Comment: And btw, try typing the full path to python.exe when running the install. That is "C:\something\something\python.exe" setup.py install

Answer (score 9):

It seems like your `xlrd` file is corrupted. So update it by using the following command :

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade xlrd
```

Comment: I've met same issue, this solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this but "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping"  this what I have

Comment: You need to upgrade to pip manually for trusted-host to work
@coding You also need to pass --trusted-host pypi.python.org on older versions. you can refer [https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5448]

Comment: Out of nowhere my py script stopped working, showing error on  "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py ". This command to upgrade xlrd has fix the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

XLRD is available for Python3.

You can get it with `sudo apt-get install python3-xlrd` or with `sudo pip3 install xlrd`

As you can see it's available here on pypi : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

Here's a dump of my console output :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-xlrd 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-xlrd is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 574 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an error with your installation or usage.
The first thing I have seen is that `print 'something'` is not used in python3  but `print('something')`. And the error shown in the code is because of using python2 with python3.

At the time of writing this answer the version of xlrd is 0.9.4. This version is compatible with both python2 and python3.

So I suggest you to update the xlrd module so that you will not face any further errors. You can do that by following any of the following steps:

```
$ pip install xlrd
```

or

```
$ easy_install xlrd
```